# ¿Cómo compruebo en Postgres si un campo es vacío o nulo?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla de Postgres (de un proyecto de Django) en la que hay distintos registros. Todos los registros tienen un campo `nombre` que es de [tipo carácter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-character.html). Sin embargo, hay casos en los que este valor está en blanco.

Lo que me interesa es saber cuáles de estos registros tienen el campo `nombre` vacío.

Así pues: ¿cómo miro en Postgres qué registros tienen un campo de tipo cadena en blanco?

Comment: ¿Quieres buscar NULL, cadenas vacías o ambas?

Comment: @PabloLozano ambas. De hecho tienes razón, mi respuesta solo abarcaba null. Actualizado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para mirar si es `null`:

```
SELECT * FROM bla WHERE nombre IS NULL
--                             ^^^^^^^
```

(Nótese que es incorrecto decir `WHERE nombre = NULL`, pues `NULL` no es "igual" a `NULL`. Véase el manual en [Comparison Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-comparison.html)).

Para mirar si es `null` o vacío se complica un poco más:

```
SELECT * FROM bla WHERE (nombre = '') IS NOT FALSE
--                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Extraído de [Best way to check for “empty or null value”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767625/1983854).